# NameError: name '_individual_decision' is not defined In my practice Source Code

Tags: python

I'm working on a simulation that shows how the entire group move as objects with different velocities move in a line. Below one is the trackback, and I can't see what is the problem here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 98, in <module>
    map_grid = MapGrid(map_width, map_height)
   File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.outside_terrain_grid = self._generate_empty_noise_grid(self.map_width, self.map_height)
   File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 49, in
_generate_empty_noise_grid
    new_map_grid[x][y] += _individual_decision(self, sum_velocity, number_count)
 NameError: name '_individual_decision' is not defined
```

Code -

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import time
import numpy


class MapGrid():
    def __init__(self, map_width, map_height):

        # set map values
        self.map_width = map_width
        self.map_height = map_width

        # generate outside rooms
        self.outside_terrain_grid = self._generate_empty_noise_grid(self.map_width, self.map_height)

    def _generate_empty_noise_grid(self, map_width, map_height):

        new_map_grid = [] # create our new list
        for x in range(map_width):
            new_map_grid.append([]) # add our columns to the array
            for y in range(map_height):
                if y < 20: 
                    new_map_grid[x].append(random.choice([0,1,2])) # fill in our rows
                else: 
                    new_map_grid[x].append(0)

            number_count = 0 
            sum_velocity = 0
            for y in range(map_height):

                if new_map_grid[x][y] != 0:
                    number_count +=1 
                    sum_velocity += new_map_grid[x][y] 
                    new_map_grid[x][y] += _individual_decision(self, sum_velocity, number_count)

        return new_map_grid

    def _individual_decision(self, sum_velocity, number_count):

        mu = 1.5 # average
        sigma = 0.125 # standard deviation 
        average_velocity = sum_velocity / number_count 
        critical_number =np.random.normal(mu, sigma)

        if average_velocity  - critical_number < 0: 
            return 1
        elif average_velocity - critical_number >= 0: 
            return 2


    def _generate_outside_terrain(self, empty_outside_terrain_grid, number_of_generations):
        '''
        creates a bubble effect with cellular automaton
        '''
        grid = empty_outside_terrain_grid
        number_of_generations = number_of_generations

        for x in range(number_of_generations):
            next_grid = []
            for column_index, column in enumerate(grid):
                next_column = []
                next_grid.append(next_column)
                for tile_index, tile in enumerate(column):

                    top_mid = grid[column_index][tile_index - 1]
                    mid = grid[column_index][tile_index]

                    d_top_mid = grid[column_index][tile_index + 1] % 2    
                    d_mid = grid[column_index][tile_index] % 2 

                    v_top_mid = math.floor((grid[column_index][tile_index+1] + 1) / 2)
                    v_mid = math.floor((grid[column_index][tile_index] + 1) / 2)

                    if d_mid <= v_top_mid:
                        grid[column_index][tile_index] == d_mid * 2 # vi = di
                        next_column+v_mid.append(grid[column_index][tile_index])

                    elif d_mid > v_top_mid: 
                        if numpy.random.randint(0,2) == 1:
                            next_grid+1[next_column.append(grid[column_index][tile_index])]

            grid = next_grid

        return next_grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # general map stats
    map_width = 140
    map_height = 30

    # start with one generation
    tile_size = 8

    map_grid = MapGrid(map_width, map_height)
    #print map_grid.outside_terrain_grid

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((map_width * tile_size,map_height * tile_size))
    zero_tile = pygame.Surface((1, 1)) 
    zero_tile.fill((0,0,0))
    one_tile = pygame.Surface((1, 1))
    one_tile.fill((255,255,255))
    two_tile = pygame.Surface((1,1))
    two_tile.fill((255,0,0))
    three_tile = pygame.Surface((1,1))
    three_tile.fill((0,0,204))
    four_tile = pygame.Surface((1,1))
    four_tile.fill((0,255,0))

    colors = {0: zero_tile, 1: one_tile, 2:two_tile}

    background = pygame.Surface((map_width * tile_size,map_height * tile_size))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    first_gen = True
    timer = 12

    running = True
    while running == True:
        clock.tick(3)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        if first_gen:
            themap = map_grid.outside_terrain_grid
        else:
            themap = map_grid._generate_outside_terrain(themap, 1)

        for column_index, column in enumerate(themap):
            for tile_index, tile in enumerate(column):
                screen.blit(colors[tile], (tile_index * tile_size, column_index * tile_size))

        pygame.display.flip()

        if first_gen:
            timer -= 1
            if timer < 0:
                first_gen = False

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_individual_decision()` is an instance method, you should call it as - `self._individual_decision()` . Code -

```
new_map_grid[x][y] += self._individual_decision(sum_velocity, number_count)
```

Also, you should not send `self` as the first arguement, just send the other arguments.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: Now I have this error
TypeError: _individual_desire() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Do you mean individual_decision?

Comment: Ok cool Glad I could be of help. I am guessing the first time you tried with `self` still in the parameter list.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 96, in <module>
    map_grid = MapGrid(map_width, map_height)
  File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.outside_terrain_grid = self._generate_empty_noise_grid(self.map_width, self.map_height)
  File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 36, in _generate_empty_noise_grid
    new_map_grid[x][y] += self._individual_desire(self, sum_velocity, number_count)
TypeError: _individual_desire() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
[Finished in 0.3s]

Comment: Hmm.... I couldn't understand your comment. Can you explain it one more time please?

Comment: Do what i do , do not send in the `self` as first argument. Check in my answer.

Comment: Oh, now I understand Thank you so much :)

Comment: The last question! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 135, in <module>
    themap = map_grid._generate_outside_terrain(themap, 1)
  File "C:\Users\JeeWoo Kim\Desktop\practice2.py", line 80, in _generate_outside_terrain
    (next_column+v_mid).append(the_value)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

I'm really sorry, I'm not used to python because I originally studied C

I don't know many grammar in python

Comment: What do you want - `(next_column+v_mid).append(the_value) ` to do?

Comment: there are objects with two real velocities and two desire velocities. there are v = 1, and v = 2. For v = 2, it must move two cell at each phase so I made it that way

Comment: `v_mid` is an int, what do you want (next_column + v_mid) to do?

Comment: move the object into +2 coordinate

Comment: next_column is a list , - `next_column + v_mid` does not work - if you want to add v_mid with some object in the list, access it using index and add it

Comment: maybe do it in two lines, first line - `next_column[<index you want>] += v_mid` , second line the append (without adding v_mid) .

Comment: Actually, I just found out that what I wanted to do was substitute previous value into the new grid and its coordinate is [column][tile_index + 2]